# What is an effective way to filter numbers according to certain number-ranges using CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I have a lot of random floating point numbers residing in global GPU memory. I also have "buckets" that specify ranges of numbers they will accept and a capacity of numbers they will accept.

ie:
numbers: -2 0 2 4
buckets(size=1): [-2, 0], [1, 5]

I want to run a filtration process that yields me

filtered_nums: -2 2
(where filtered_nums can be a new block of memory)

But every approach I take runs into a huge overhead of trying to synchronize threads across bucket counters. If I try to use a single-thread, the algorithm completes successfully, but takes frighteningly long (over 100 times slower than generating the numbers in the first place).

What I am asking for is a general high-level, efficient, as-simple-as-possible approach algorithm that you would use to filter these numbers.

**edit**
I will be dealing with 10 buckets and half a million numbers. Where all the numbers fall into exactly 1 of the 10 bucket ranges. Each bucket will hold 43000 elements. (There are excess elements, since the objective is to fill every bucket, and many numbers will be discarded).

**2nd edit**
It's important to point out that the buckets do not have to be stored individually. The objective is just to discard elements that would not fit into a bucket.

Comment: Could you please give a ballpark on how many numbers and buckets do you have and what are ranges for bucket size. The optimal solution for {2 buckets 1000 elements each} and for {1000 buckets 2 elements each} cases may vary...

Comment: @aland: I updated the questionw with the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use thrust::remove_copy_if

```
struct within_limit
{
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(const int x)
        {
            return (x >=lo && x < hi);
        }
};
thrust::remove_copy_if(input, input + N, result, within_limit());
```

You will have to replace lo and hi with constants for each bin.. 
I think you can templatize the kernel, but then again you will have to instantiate the template with actual constants. I can't see an easy way at it, but I may be missing something.

If you are willing to look at third party libraries, arrayfire may offer an easier solution.

```
array I = array(N, input, afDevice);
float **Res = (float **)malloc(sizeof(float *) * nbins);
for(int i = 0; i < nbins; i++) {
   array res = where(I >= lo[i] && I < hi[i]);
   Res[i] = res.device<float>(); 
}
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to keep track of a counter for each bin in the thrust example? (You could run the filtration NUM_BINS times and then pop off the desired amount, but that seems like it would be expensive)